# Почему аннотация @inject работает в сервлете и фильтрах, но не работает в других классах

Tags: java, tomcat, dependency-injection, di

В качестве контейнера используется TomEE. Аннотирую класс ДАО. В сервлете инъекция отлично работает, это видно по sysout. Но в классе Test dao всегда null.

```
    public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    @OracleAnnotation
    private DAO dao;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(dao);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

Для указания конкретной реализации интерфейса использую аннотацию @OracleAnnotation

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
    ElementType.METHOD, 
    ElementType.FIELD, 
    ElementType.PARAMETER, 
    ElementType.TYPE
    })
public @interface OracleAnnotation {}
```

Этой же аннотацией помечена реализация интерфейса DAO

```
@ApplicationScoped
@OracleAnnotation
public class OracleDAO implements DAO {

    private static final int DEFAULT_ID = -1;

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() throws DAOException {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public int insertNewBook(Book book) throws DAOException {
        //some code  
    }
}
```

В классе Test всегда null

```
    public class Test {

    @Inject
    @OracleAnnotation
    private DAO dao;

    public Test() {}

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(dao);
    }
}
```

Перерыл много всего в поисках ответа но даже близко не могу понять в чем дело, по идее же инъекция работает и в сервлете и в фильтрах я получаю конкретный экземпляр ДАО, но в других классах всегда null

Comment: Вы создаете экземпляр класса Test через new, необходимо чтобы Вам его создал инжектор

Comment: я мучался с этим неделю, пытаясь понять сам, вы меня спасли! спасибо, да так действительно все ок!